# I can't figure out how it works if/else in nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, pycharm

please tell me something,  I can not understand

```
test1 = [{'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112233', 'idd': '0000123'},
         {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112234', 'idd': '0000124'},
         {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112235', 'idd': '0000125'},
         {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112236', 'idd': '0000126'}
         ]
test2 = [
         {'Data': ['03.02.2023'], 'id': ['112233'], 'idd': ['333444']},
         {'Data': ['03.02.2023'], 'id': ['112255'], 'idd': ['555535']},
         {'Data': ['03.02.2023'], 'id': ['112288'], 'idd': ['223455']}
         ]
​
for a in test1:
    for b in test2:
        if b['id'][0] == a['id']:
            print(a)
```

If do if b['id'][0] == a['id']:  prints what matches {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112233', 'idd': '0000123'}

I don't understand why when I do if b['id'][0] != a['id'] everything is displayed, a lot of times, why does not it display what is not there?
Example:

```
         {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112234', 'idd': '0000124'},
         {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112235', 'idd': '0000125'},
         {'DataTime': '03.02.2023', 'id': '112236', 'idd': '0000126'}
```

Thank you

Tell me, most likely it will be possible to compare differently. Why doesn't it work with if b['id'][0] != a['id']: ?
How to make the difference then?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the last part of your question but answering the first part on why everything is displayed when using `if b['id'][0] != a['id']` is because it keeps printing the content of `a` every time `b['id'][0] != a['id'` is satisfied. Meaning when iteration 2 or inner loop is 112255 that is not equal to outer loop iteration 1's 112233 thus it prints 112233 several times and similarly for rest of all iterations.

Comment: Exactly, thanks, I understand why this is happening.

I corrected the second question.

How do I compare two lists of dictionaries by value b['id'][0] ? (

Comment: This isn't  a discussion forum or tutorial.  https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 0):

You're using nested for loops, so the `if` comparison will be executed once per combination of each item in both lists.

The first list has four items and the second list has three, so there are 4x3 = 12 combinations.

There is only one combination where the id matches: the first item in both lists.  So, if you print the *matches*, then `a` will print once.

But there are eleven combinations where the ids do *not* match.  So if you print the *non-matches*, then `a` will be printed eleven times.

Comment: Thank you, I already understood how to get the difference by value?

Answer (score -1):

```
for a in test1:
    if all(a['id'] != b['id'][0] for b in test2):
        print(a)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.